ERROR] [MY-013882] [InnoDB] Missing redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo1292 (with start_lsn = 4230987776)
sudo cat /opt/bitnami/mysql/logs/mysqld.log
2024-10-27T07:54:59.478600Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.35).
2024-10-27T07:55:01.598187Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 19496  user: 'bn_mattermost'.
2024-10-27T07:55:01.598399Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 19624  user: 'bn_mattermost'.
2024-10-27T07:55:01.598490Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 19618  user: 'bn_mattermost'.
2024-10-27T07:55:01.598610Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 19005  user: 'bn_mattermost'.
2024-10-27T07:55:01.598711Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 19454  user: 'bn_mattermost'.
2024-10-27T07:55:01.598818Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 19623  user: 'bn_mattermost'.
2024-10-27T07:55:04.172354Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35)  Source distribution.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%2024-10-28T04:53:41.719203Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35) starting as process 2410934
2024-10-28T04:53:41.959977Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-10-28T04:53:43.575311Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013882] [InnoDB] Missing redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo1292 (with start_lsn = 4230987776).
2024-10-28T04:53:43.575375Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2024-10-28T04:53:43.674441Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2024-10-28T04:53:43.674754Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2024-10-28T04:53:43.674796Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-10-28T04:53:43.689846Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35)  Source distribution.
2024-10-28T04:56:39.833310Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35) starting as process 2411144
2024-10-28T04:56:39.850289Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-10-28T04:56:41.063343Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013882] [InnoDB] Missing redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo1292 (with start_lsn = 4230987776).
2024-10-28T04:56:41.063395Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2024-10-28T04:56:41.416893Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2024-10-28T04:56:41.417157Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2024-10-28T04:56:41.417200Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-10-28T04:56:41.417837Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35)  Source distribution.
2024-10-28T04:58:39.211474Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35) starting as process 2411267
2024-10-28T04:58:39.221770Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-10-28T04:58:40.078596Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013882] [InnoDB] Missing redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo1292 (with start_lsn = 4230987776).
2024-10-28T04:58:40.078647Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2024-10-28T04:58:40.496715Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2024-10-28T04:58:40.496998Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2024-10-28T04:58:40.497041Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-10-28T04:58:40.497739Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35)  Source distribution.
2024-10-28T04:59:58.332324Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35) starting as process 2411447
2024-10-28T04:59:58.345141Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-10-28T04:59:59.454446Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013882] [InnoDB] Missing redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo1292 (with start_lsn = 4230987776).
2024-10-28T04:59:59.454502Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2024-10-28T04:59:59.829494Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2024-10-28T04:59:59.829793Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2024-10-28T04:59:59.829837Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-10-28T04:59:59.830457Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35)  Source distribution.
2024-10-28T05:04:30.093217Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35) starting as process 2411689
2024-10-28T05:04:30.104180Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-10-28T05:04:31.153706Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013882] [InnoDB] Missing redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo1292 (with start_lsn = 4230987776).
2024-10-28T05:04:31.153915Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2024-10-28T05:04:31.563530Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2024-10-28T05:04:31.563787Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2024-10-28T05:04:31.563853Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-10-28T05:04:31.564498Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35)  Source distribution.
2024-10-28T06:16:42.688464Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35) starting as process 2412572
2024-10-28T06:16:42.849064Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-10-28T06:16:44.206632Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013882] [InnoDB] Missing redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo1292 (with start_lsn = 4230987776).
2024-10-28T06:16:44.206696Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2024-10-28T06:16:44.356909Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2024-10-28T06:16:44.357168Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2024-10-28T06:16:44.357210Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-10-28T06:16:44.365658Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35)  Source distribution.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
